# How to Understand Code

Tags: c

I was given this code recently that I am having a hard  time understanding. I am very new to programming overall and am still learning. Any information about this would be greatly appreciated. This is the code as it appears:

```
void enc(char* plaintxt, unsigned char key) 
{ 
    while(*plaintxt)
    { 
        *plaintxt^ = (key=(key*13)+37);
        *(plaintxt++) +=3;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0F A8 9F FE 7A D6 E2 08 AE 2B 5F 53 25 9A
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python` and `C++`? It looks like standard C and no Python.

Comment: Before trying to understand any code, try using beautifier, just google for "c code beautifier" and you will get it.

Comment: My mistake. I changed the tag to c

Comment: This code doesn't output anything.

Comment: @JoaoPedro So what you're not understanding in particular? What's the context of this code is used? Your code snipped doesn't provide any output BTW, please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: try rewrite it with more lines

Comment: I think this is somewhat outside the scope of SO, which aimed at more specific programming questions, there are many resources on the internet which provide introductory courses and other materials which you should consult. [TutorialsPoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) just to name a few.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It does modify the content of `plaintxt`

Comment: @BryanChen Does that produce the output as claimed?

Comment: How to understand code: Learn the language that the code is written in.

Answer (score 6):

It would help to know what *specific* questions you have.

In short, this code is taking a string and encrypting/encoding it using a key value.  The line

```
*plaintxt^ = (key=(key*13)+37);
```

is a very dense way of writing

```
*plaintxt = *plaintxt ^ (key * 13 + 37);
key = key * 13 + 37;
```

with the caveat that the exact order in which `key` and `*plaintxt` are updated isn't specified (IOW, in the original code `key` may be updated before or after `*plaintxt` is updated).

The `^` operator is the bitwise-XOR operator; each bit in `*plaintext` is XOR'd against each bit in `key`.

The line

```
 *(plaintxt++) +=3;
```

is a dense way of writing

```
 *plaintxt = *plaintxt + 3;
 plaintxt = plaintxt + 1;
```

with the same caveat that the exact order in which `*plaintxt` and `plaintxt` are updated isn't specified.  This line is adding `3` to `*plaintext`, and then advancing the pointer to point to the next character in the string.

In C, strings are sequences of character values terminated by a `0`.  `plaintext` is a pointer to the first character of the string.  The `while` loop is checking to see that we haven't reached the end of the string by testing the value of `*plaintxt`; `while ( *plaintext )` is the same as `while ( *plaintext != 0 )`.

So, let's suppose `plaintext` is pointing to the string `"test"`<sup>1</sup>:

```
           +---+              +----+
plaintext: |   | ----> "test" | 74 |    Assumes ASCII, all values in hex
           +---+              +----+
                              | 65 |
           +----+             +----+
      key: |  1 |             | 75 |
           +----+             +----+
                              | 74 |
                              +----+
                              |  0 |
                              +----+
```

and that `key` is initially 1.

At the start of the loop, `plaintext` is pointing to the first `t` in `"test"` (ASCII `0x74`).  We XOR this with the result of `key * 13 + 37`, which is 50 in decimal, or 0x32 in hex:

```
  0x74 ^ 0x32 == 0x46
```

We write this value back to `*plaintext`, and then add 3 to it, giving us 0x49.  We save 0x32 to `key`.  We then advance `plaintext` to point to the next character in the string, giving us:

```
           +---+              +----+
plaintext: |   | --+   "Iest" | 49 |    
           +---+   |          +----+
                   +------->  | 65 |
           +----+             +----+
      key: | 32 |             | 75 |
           +----+             +----+
                              | 74 |
                              +----+
                              |  0 |
                              +----+
```

Now we do the same thing with the `e`:

```
key = 50 * 13 + 37 == 687 % 255 == 177 == 0xb1
```

`unsigned char` can only store values from 0 to 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup>-1, which on most modern systems is 255; 687 is too large to store in `key`, so it "wraps around" back to 177, or 0xb1<sup>2</sup>.

```
0x65 ^ 0xb1 == 0xd4
0xd4 + 3    == 0xd7
```

After that's all done, we have

```
           +---+              +----+
plaintext: |   | --+   "I?st" | 49 |    
           +---+   |          +----+
                   |          | d7 |  
           +----+  |          +----+
      key: | b1 |  +--------> | 75 |
           +----+             +----+
                              | 74 |
                              +----+
                              |  0 |
                              +----+
```

Lather, rinse, repeat.  This will continue until `plaintext` points to the memory cell containing 0.

---

1. Technically, it's pointing to an *array* that contains the string `"test"`, not to the *string literal* `"test"`.  String literals may not have their contents modified; attempting to do so invokes undefined behavior.

   This is only true for *unsigned* integral types; overflow on signed integral types is not well-defined, and may not behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, and whatever security conference you got that card from is long over (Raytheon Game Of Pwns)... but let me save you some frustration.
You won't find a better description of what the code is doing than what appears above, but you do not need to recreate this code at all to solve the cipher.
You don't even need to know C.
in whichever language you choose, you can generate the key to crack this code easily. 
Given that there are only 256 possible values for the initial key (0-255), you can brute force it, but you can solve this with an educated guess to get the first value of the key.

The Game Of Pwns card contains keys, which you probably noticed from solving the binary encoded ASCII message that resolved to Key=2EZ01. You can guess that the first character is probably an uppercase K (0x4B).
The fun fact about an XOR operation is that it can be used to reverse itself.
Let's take the premise that the first character is indeed a K, and we already know that the first output element is 0x0F (which is really 0x0C). this tells us that
Flag ^ key = (output-3)
the trick is that 
(output-3) ^ Flag = key !
based on that assumption, we can obtain the first result of `((key*13)+37)`which would be 0x0C ^ 0x4B = 0x47.

two important notes,the 13 and 37 in the code are indeed decimal values, not hex and the flag is incremented by 3 before indexing to the next char in the array.

With the first key, you can generate the rest of the keys in whatever language you choose by creating a loop to give you the next 13 keys using
`((key*13)+37)%256)`
The %256 mimics the wraparound behavior of the unsigned char in C.
When you have the 14 keys, simply XOR each key in the list with it's corresponding original output (-3) to get the encoded message, which is clear... it begins Key=
If you also got the other card from Raytheon with similar looking code, all of the ciphers on that card begin with Flag=, so you can simply apply what you learned here about XOR to crack that one easily as well.